# How to kill process associated with the buffer before killing the buffer?

Tags: emacs, process, elisp

I'm trying to terminate Flymake process before leaving closing the buffer it operates on, albeit unsuccessfully. Below is what I've tried:

```
(defun haxe-kill-network-process ()
  "Kill connection to Haxe compiler server and Flymake process in this buffer"
  (when (equal major-mode 'haxe-mode)
    (let ((proc (get-process haxe-compiler-process))
      (fly-proc (get-buffer-process (buffer-name))))
      (when proc
    (delete-process proc)
    (haxe-log 3 "Disconnecting from HaXe compiler server")
    (flymake-mode -1)
    (delete-process fly-proc)
    (haxe-log 3 "Flymake process killed")))))

(add-hook 'kill-buffer-hook #'haxe-kill-network-process)
```

I get this output:

> Disconnecting from Haxe compiler server
>
> switched OFF Flymake mode for
>   buffer StripArray.hx due to fatal status CFGERR,  warning
>   Configuration error has occurred while running  (haxe --connect
>   127.0.0.1:1257 --cwd /home/wvxvw/projects/wafer/src 
>   -swf /home/wvxvw/projects/wafer/bin/wunderwafer.swf -cp /home/wvxvw/projects/wafer/src 
>   -swf-header 800:600:31 -swf-version 10 com.wunderwafer.map.StripArray)
>
> Flymake process killed

But it isn't killed by `haxe-kill-network-process` - it still prompts me for terminating it when I attempt to kill the buffer running the process.

Answer (score 2):

We'd need more information to figure out what happens exactly, but here are some thoughts:

- you might like to try and `set-process-query-on-exit-flag` to avoid the prompt.
- always prefer buffers over buffer names (i.e. use `(current-buffer)` rather than `(buffer-name)`.
- you say "it isn't killed" but your code seems to indicate there are various processes involved.  So which process isn't killed?  What's the exact prompt you get?  You might also like to use `M-x list-processes` to se the runing processes.